# Compare 2 Vectors of unknown length to find a common value? - R

Tags: r, statistics

How do you compare two Vectors in **R**, and find the last common "TRUE" value along the elements?

It's a bit hard to explain, so here's an example:

```
  Element:  [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5]    [6]    [7]    [8]  [9]   [10]
  vec1 <- TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE,  NA, FALSE,
  vec2 <- TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,   NA, FALSE, FALSE,    NA,  NA,    NA,
```

How can I compare `vec1` and `vec2` to find that Element 4 is the last common `TRUE` they share? and assuming the vectors are not always of the same length?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this got down-voted... It's a valid query which doesn't already have an answer on SO... All the answers below do the trick though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bits of interest for your example are `which` and `intersect`.  Here is a reproducible example below.

```
vec1 = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),10, replace=TRUE)
vec2 = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),10, replace=TRUE)
max(intersect(which(vec1), which(vec2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l <- min(length(vec1), length(vec2))
tail(which((vec1[1:l] == vec2[1:l])), 1)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer as he is looking for "the last common TRUE". From the example I also think we can assume that the vectors are of equal length.

Comment: True,  "==" should be "&". If the vectors are guaranteed to be of equal length, the first line is of course not necessary

Comment: How would it affect your answer if each vector had a different length? That would be nice to include if it's feasible to of course.

Comment: This works even if the vectors are not of equal length. In that case, comparing only the first min(length(vec1), length(vec2)) elements is essential, otherwise the shorter vector is recycled. But the answer by Matt Weller also works for vectors of unequal length and looks more elegant...

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for the answer. They all work well. It's nice to have some variation to learn with. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach because a logical value (F=0 and T=1) when summed that adds to 2 means you had 2 `TRUE`.  So we simply add the two vectors, use `which` to find the indices of those `==` to 2 and then take the last one with `tail`:

```
tail(which(vec1 + vec2 == 2), 1)
```